# Page load without refresh in svelte and dynamic routing

Tags: graphql, svelte, svelte-component, dynamic-routing, sveltekit

What is the best way to load a page without refreshing using graphql and dynamic routing.
I have a file called `kindergarten` that loads perfectly without refreshing the whole page :

```js
<script context="module">
  import { gql, GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'

  export async function load() {
    const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(import.meta.env.VITE_GRAPHCMS_URL, {
      headers: {},
    })

    const query = gql`
      query MyQuery {
        terms(where: { taxonomies: CATEGORY }) {
          nodes {
            slug
            name
            termTaxonomyId
          }
        }
      }
    `

    const { terms } = await graphcms.request(query)

    return {
      props: {
        posts: terms.nodes,
      },
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  import { SITE_NAME } from '$lib/store.js'
  let date = new Date()
  const [month, day, year] = [
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getDate(),
    date.getFullYear(),
  ]
  export let posts = []
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>Sample Title - {SITE_NAME}</title>
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="Sample description  [Update: {year}/{month}/{day}]" />
</svelte:head>

{#each posts as post (post.termTaxonomyId)}
  <a
    tax-id={post.termTaxonomyId}
    href="/kindergarten/province/{post.slug}"
    target="blank">
    {post.name}
  </a>
  <br />
{/each}
```

and also I have another page called `[slug].svelte` :

```js
<script context="module">
  import { gql, GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'
  export async function load(ctx) {
    let slug = ctx.page.params.slug
    const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(import.meta.env.VITE_GRAPHCMS_URL, {
      headers: {},
    })

    const query = gql`
      query MyQuery {
        terms(where: { taxonomies: CATEGORY, slug: "${slug}" }) {
          nodes {
            name
            description
          }
        }
      }
    `

    const { terms } = await graphcms.request(query)
    return { props: { slug, post: terms.nodes } }
  }
</script>

<script>
  import { SITE_NAME } from '$lib/store.js'
  export let slug
  export let post
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>{post[0].name} - {SITE_NAME}</title>
</svelte:head>

<h1>Slug : {slug}</h1>
{#each post as data}
  <p>Name: {data.name}</p>
  <br />
  {#if data.description}
    <p>Description: {data.description}</p>
  {:else}
    <p>Ther is no Description</p>
  {/if}
{/each}
```

When I click a link on `kindergarten` page it goes to the subpage but refreshes the whole site.
**How can I optimize the `[slug].svelte` file to prevent refreshing the page?**
As I'm new to Svelte and Sveltekit, any ideas for optimizing the whole code is appreciated.

Comment: I found something wired!
I had a `target=blank` in my `kindergarten.svelte` file that when I click on a link that opens in a new tab , in that tab when I click on other links page doesn't load without refresh!
It's a little bit confusing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking to a new page, so it makes sense it refreshes, because it's going to a whole new page (`[slug].svelte`). It sounds like you're trying to load data into your `kindergarten.svelte` page? In that case, make a component, not a page, where you can pass in data to the component, and the component will be updated, rather than the entire page. Check out an example from the docs here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings